# Java : Genrics - Two similar codes, one doesn't work

Tags: java, generics

The below code doesn't work :

```
    class Stats<T extends Number>
    {
    T[] nums; 

    Stats(T[] o)
    {
        nums = o;
    }

    double average()
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++)
            sum += nums[i].doubleValue();
        return sum / nums.length;
    }

    boolean sameAvg(Stats<T> ob) 
    {
        if(average() == ob.average())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

class BoundsDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Integer inums[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Stats<Integer> iob = new Stats<Integer>(inums);
        double v = iob.average();
        System.out.println("iob average is " + v);

        Double dnums[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5 };
        Stats<Double> dob = new Stats<Double>(dnums);
        double w = dob.average();
        System.out.println("dob average is " + w);

        if(iob.sameAvg(dob))
            System.out.println("Averages are the same.");
        else
            System.out.println("Averages differ.");
    }
}
```

But, the following works:

```
    class Gen04<T extends Number>
    {
    T num;
    void set(T a)
    {
        num = a;
    }

    T get()
    {
        return num;
    }

    boolean equals(Gen04<T> ob)
    {
        if(num.doubleValue() == ob.get().doubleValue())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
class GenericCompare
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Gen04<Integer> obI1 = new Gen04<Integer>();
        obI1.set(new Integer(5));

        Gen04<Double> obI2 = new Gen04<Double>();
        obI2.set(new Double(5.0));

        System.out.println("obI1 and obI2 are equal = "+obI1.equals(obI2));
    }
}
```

What is the difference ? In both the programs, I am trying to call a method with parameter type different from the parameter type of the invoking object

Comment: Can you explain exactly what "doesn't work?"  What error do you get?

Comment: Are you getting any error or wrong answer?

Comment: Error : Incompatible types : Stats<Double> cannot be converted to Stats<Integer>

Comment: I think that error message is quite clear.  You are trying to convert a `Stats<Double>` to a `Stats<Integer>`.  You cannot do that.

Answer (score 3):

In the first snippet, in `iob.sameAvg(dob)` you attempt to pass a `Stats<Double>` instance to a method of `Stats<Integer>`, which expects a `Stats<Integer>` argument. Since `Stats<Double>` is not a sub-class of `Stats<Integer>`, the compiler doesn't accept it.

In the second snippet you call `obI1.equals(obI2)`. `equals` is a method of `Object` class that accepts an `Object` argument, so you can pass any `Object` instance to it.

EDIT : I see were you got confused. Your second snippet has an `equals(Gen04<T> ob)` method that overloads `Object`'s `equals`, but that method is not being called. Instead, the compiler chooses the `equals(Object other)` method of `Object` class. If you rename your `equals` method and call the renamed method from your `main`, the second snippet would produce the same error.

Comment: Since you did all the work figuring this out, I'll just add that I think if the OP changes his declaration to `boolean sameAvg(Stats<?> ob)`, I think the method call will work as desired.